# How mock a child function's output inside a parent that is being tested?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm wondering how I can mock the output of a child function inside a parent function during tests so the subsequent conditionals can be tested.

```
const someFunction = async () => {
  const {x, y} = await functionThatFetchesObject();
    // how to mock x,y values so following code can be tested?
  if (x) {
    // some code
  } else if (y) {
    // some code
  } else {
    // some code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to test the output of an API call, which is great!  You could try extracting `functionThatFetchesObject` to a seperate file, and then testing that function specifically with [Jest Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html)